# Foundation for Emails - Columns and Rows are misaligned on small?

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I am having difficulties trying to create an email for the company I work for. It seems that something is misaligned. I'm not sure how to fix this. Any help?

**HTML (Cropped for readability)**

```
 <body>
   <table align="center" class="container">
     <tbody>
       <tr>
         <td>
           <table class="row">
             <tbody>
               <tr>
                 <th class="large-6 small-12 columns">         <-- OVERFLOWS
                   <table>
                       <tr>
                         <th>
                           <h5 class="text-center lead">Lieferadresse</h5>
                           <p class="text-center sub">Fredrick Müller</p>
                           <p class="text-center sub">Apfelstraße 12</p>
                           <p class="text-center sub">95468 Weiden</p>
                           <p class="text-center sub">Germany</p>
                         </th>
                       </tr>
                     </table>
                   </th>
                 </tr>
               </tbody>
             </table>
           </td>
         </tr>
       </tbody>
     </table>
   </body>
```

---

**Problem Description**

When the screen shrinks to the `small` breakpoint, it seems that the `large` breakpoint styles are not removed. I believe this is causing the problem, but unaware as to how to fix it.

The `th` tag that I pointed out in the code overflows the table causing the whole document to not be responsive.

In my actual code, not shown here, I have two `th` tags with the classes `first` and `last` respectively. These classes seems to make it worse, but on the `large` breakpoint everything is aligned.

It case anyone wants to replicate the problem, here is the CDN:

```
<!-- Foundation for Emails -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation-emails/2.2.1/foundation-emails.css" />
```

Here is the problem for Google DevTools. As you can see the large styles are still affecting the element. Causing abnormal `padding` and misalignment.

[image: Google DevTools]

---

EDIT

Here is an image showing off the problem.

[image: Google Devtools]

Thank you,

Lars

Comment: I'm not seeing any issues? Can you paste a image of the problem?

Comment: @RasmusGlenvig Please check my edited answer.

Comment: As I see it, is it the "first" class that gives the padding-left: 16px

Comment: @RasmusGlenvig Correct. However, even with the class removed, like in the code I have in my answer, it still has a `padding` offset derived from the `large` classes.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do was, give the `<th class="large-6 small-12 columns" style="padding-left: 8px;">` and then they both will be in the center.

Code snippet:

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation-emails/2.2.1/foundation-emails.css" />
 
 <body>
   <table align="center" class="container">
     <tbody>
       <tr>
         <td>
           <table class="row">
             <tbody>
               <tr>
                 <th class="large-6 small-12 columns first" style="padding-left: 8px;">         
                   <table>
                       <tr>
                         <th>
                           <h5 class="text-center lead">Rechnungsadresse</h5>
                           <p class="text-center sub">Fredrick Müller</p>
                           <p class="text-center sub">Apfelstraße 12</p>
                           <p class="text-center sub">95468 Weiden</p>
                           <p class="text-center sub">Germany</p>
                         </th>
                       </tr>
                     </table>
                   </th>
                   <th class="large-6 small-12 columns last">         
                   <table>
                       <tr>
                         <th>
                           <h5 class="text-center lead">Lieferadresse</h5>
                           <p class="text-center sub">Fredrick Müller</p>
                           <p class="text-center sub">Apfelstraße 12</p>
                           <p class="text-center sub">95468 Weiden</p>
                           <p class="text-center sub">Germany</p>
                         </th>
                       </tr>
                     </table>
                   </th>
                 </tr>
               </tbody>
             </table>
           </td>
         </tr>
       </tbody>
     </table>
   </body>
```

Comment: I do appreciate the answer you gave very much, however this is a work-around and I unfortunately can not use it in our production code. The problem should be with the table structure, somewhere I made a mistake.

Comment: Even with the `padding` fix, it still seems to overflow. :(

Comment: Alright, instead of using zurb foundation for emails I can highly recommend MJML, which IMO is much easier to work with. I am using it myself. https://mjml.io/